# Splice IEnumerable with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Is there an in-built way to splice an `IEnumerable` in Linq-To-Objects?

Something like:

```
List<string> options = new List<string>(); // Array of 20 strings
List<string> lastOptions = options.Splice(1, 5); // Gets me all strings 1 through 5 into a new list
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
List<string> options = new List<string>();
List<string> lastOptions = options.Skip(0).Take(5).ToList();
```

*skip is used to show how to skip x elements*   (tnx drch)

---

You could create something like this:  *(extension method)*

```
public static class SpliceExtension
{
    public static List<T> Splice<T>(this List<T> list, int offset, int count)
    {
        return list.Skip(offset).Take(count).ToList();
    }
}
```

But this will only be available to Lists.

---

You could also use it on `IEnumerable<>`

```
public static class SpliceExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Splice<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int offset, int count)
    {
        return list.Skip(offset).Take(count);
    }
}
```

This way the List isn't iterated completely.

use it like:

```
List<string> lastOptions = options.Splice(1, 5).ToList();
```

I like this way more, because it can be used on several linq queries.

Comment: FYI, skip is the number of elements to skip, not the index of the item to skip.

Comment: There is also [List<T>.GetRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) if you don't/can't use Linq.

Comment: Very nice one @Ahmed KRAIEM, didn't knew that...tnx +1

Answer (score 0):

There is no mentioning yet of the difference between JavaScript's `slice` and `splice`.

Note that `splice` also changes the original array in JavaScript whereas `slice` does not. The accepted answer is therefore a port of `slice`.

For completeness, here's a port of `splice`:

```cs
public static class SpliceExtension
{
    public static List<T> Splice<T>(this List<T> list, int start, int count)
    {
        var listWithDeletedElements = list.GetRange(start, count);
        list.RemoveRange(start, count);
        return listWithDeletedElements;
    }
}
```